How to do a hard factory reset on a Canon imageCLASS LBP253dw
I just purchased a new Canon imageCLASS LBP253dw printer from Amazon. I unboxed this and installed the drivers on my computer. It will print from my computer but will not allow me to enter the System Manager mode without a login and password. The paperwork that comes from the factory that was in the box says that the Default Login is 7654321 and the password is 7654321. I used this on the printer itself and have tried through the web browser interface for this printer on my local network, neither allowed me access. My only option that I can think of is to do a hard factory reset. Does anyone know how to do this for this model? I have tried the hard rest processes for a few other Canon's but this model is much different than those and none of them seems to work. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

I finally got a hold of Canon Support. Which wasn't really all that long, I'm just impatient. They got me up and going in less than 15 minutes. The instructions are simple. power off the printer. Then hold the number 4 key down on the number keypad while powering up. Once you see the home screen menu let go of the number 4 key. That is it, now you should be able to see all the settings.

Unbelievable that they replied everyone on the forums “call us”.
